# Local gauge transformation in Fock space of charged particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, charge, gauge-theory

I'm currently fiddling around with gauge-phase-transformations in Fock space.
Especially, I'm trying to write a local gauge-phase-transformation as
an operator in a basis-independent way.

Here is what I have so far.
Consider a system of indistinguishable particles (each with a charge $q$).

#### Total charge

Let's take the total charge operator $\hat{Q}$. It can be defined
by its action on the $n$-particle states (using Fock states in the position basis):
$$\begin{align}
&\hat{Q}\ |\rangle &=\ & 0 \\
&\hat{Q}\ |\vec{x}_1\rangle &=\ & q\ |\vec{x}_1\rangle \\
&\hat{Q}\ |\vec{x}_1\vec{x}_2\rangle &=\ & 2q\ |\vec{x}_1\vec{x}_2\rangle \\
&...
\end{align} \tag{1}$$
The operator $\hat{Q}$ can be written in a basis-independent way:
$$\hat{Q} = q\hat{N} = q\int d^3x\ \hat{\psi}^\dagger(\vec{x})\hat{\psi}(\vec{x}) \tag{2}$$
where $\hat{N}$ is the total number operator, and
$\hat{\psi}^\dagger(\vec{x})$ and $\hat{\psi}(\vec{x})$ are the canonical
creation and annihilation operators at position $\vec{x}$.
It is easy to check that this operator (2) satifies the definition (1).

#### Global gauge transformation

Now let's consider a global gauge-phase-transformation $\hat{U}(f)$
with a global constant $f$. $\hat{U}(f)$ can be defined by its action
on the $n$-particle states:
$$\begin{align}
&\hat{U}(f)\ |\rangle &=\ & |\rangle \\
&\hat{U}(f)\ |\vec{x}_1\rangle &=\ & e^{iqf}\ |\vec{x}_1\rangle \\
&\hat{U}(f)\ |\vec{x}_1\vec{x}_2\rangle &=\ & e^{2iqf}\ |\vec{x}_1\vec{x}_2\rangle \\
&...
\end{align} \tag{3}$$
It is easy to guess that $\hat{U}(f)$ can be written
in a basis-independent way:
$$\hat{U}(f) = e^{i\hat{Q}f} \tag{4}$$
And indeed, by using $\hat{Q}$ from above
it can be verified that (4) satisfies the definition (3).

So far no problem.

#### Local gauge transformation

And now for the local gauge-phase-transformation $\hat{U}(f)$
with a position-dependent function $f(\vec{x})$.
Again $\hat{U}(f)$ can be defined by its action on the $n$-particle states
(by generalizing the definition (3)):
$$\begin{align}
&\hat{U}(f)\ |\rangle &=\ & |\rangle \\
&\hat{U}(f)\ |\vec{x}_1\rangle
  &=\ & e^{iqf(\vec{x}_1)}\ |\vec{x}_1\rangle \\
&\hat{U}(f)\ |\vec{x}_1\vec{x}_2\rangle
  &=\ & e^{iqf(\vec{x}_1)}\ e^{iqf(\vec{x}_2)}\ |\vec{x}_1\vec{x}_2\rangle \\
...
\end{align} \tag{5}$$

I was not able to write $\hat{U}(f)$ in a basis-independent way
so that it will satisfy the definition (5).

- $\hat{U}(f) = \int d^3x\ e^{i\hat{Q}f(\vec{x})}$
  is obviously wrong, because $\hat{U}$ has the dimension of a volume,
  instead of being dimensionless.
- $\hat{U}(f) = e^{i\int d^3x\ \hat{Q}f(\vec{x})}$
  is also wrong, because the exponent has the dimension of a volume,
  instead of being dimensionless.
- $\hat{U}(f) = \int d^3x\ \hat{\psi}^\dagger(\vec{x})
    e^{i\hat{Q}f(\vec{x})} \hat{\psi}(\vec{x})$
  is wrong, because when acting on the vacuum state
  the result is $\hat{U}|\rangle=0$ instead of $\hat{U}|\rangle=|\rangle$.

Any ideas? Is it even possible?

Comment: One thought is that, with a discrete number of points $N$, $\prod_{j=1}^{N} e^{i \hat{Q} f(\vec{x}_j)} = {\rm exp}[ \sum_{j=1}^N i \hat{Q} f(\vec{x}_j)]$ would work. In the limit $N\rightarrow \infty$ you'd get something like your second bullet point. But I guess the continuum limit is tricky, maybe one should replace $f$ or $\hat{Q}$ with a density. Another thought, is that the Hilbert space you get when quantizing a gauge theory depends on the gauge you choose, and in the end you want to restrict to a physical subspace. So, the states you are constructing should be identified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm quite sure the answer is
$$\hat{U}(f) = e^{iq\int d^3x\ f(\vec{x})\hat{\psi}^\dagger(\vec{x})\hat{\psi}(\vec{x})}$$
<s>But I wasn't able to prove it. So it is only a conjecture.</s>

For the special case of $f(\vec{x})=f=\text{const}$, the above reduces to
$$\begin{align}
\hat{U}(f) &= e^{iq\int d^3x\ f\ \hat{\psi}^\dagger(\vec{x})\hat{\psi}(\vec{x})} \\
 &= e^{iqf\int d^3x\ \hat{\psi}^\dagger(\vec{x})\hat{\psi}(\vec{x})} \\
 &= e^{iqf\hat{N}} \\
 &= e^{i\hat{Q}f}
\end{align}$$
which is just the global gauge transformation from equation (4) in the question.

---

@ChiralAnomaly in his comment has already sketched an elegant proof using operator algebra.

Here is another proof on a more elementary level.

Let's use the abbreviation
$$\hat{Q}(f)=\int d^3x f(\vec{x})\hat{\psi}^\dagger(\vec{x})\hat{\psi}(\vec{x}).$$

By applying $\hat{Q}(f)$ to an $n$-particle state we get
$$\begin{align}
 & \hat{Q}(f) |\vec{x}_1 ... \vec{x}_n\rangle \\
=& \int d^3x f(\vec{x})\hat{\psi}^\dagger(\vec{x})\hat{\psi}(\vec{x}) |\vec{x}_1 ... \vec{x}_n\rangle \\
=& \int d^3x f(\vec{x})\sum_{k=1}^n \delta(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_k) |\vec{x}_1 ... \vec{x}_n\rangle \\
=& \sum_{k=1}^n f(\vec{x}_k) |\vec{x}_1 ... \vec{x}_n\rangle
\end{align}$$

By applying $\hat{Q}(f)$ again and again we get (for $j=1,2,3,...$)
$$\left(\hat{Q}(f)\right)^j |\vec{x}_1 ... \vec{x}_n\rangle
= \left(\sum_{k=1}^n f(\vec{x}_k)\right)^j |\vec{x}_1 ... \vec{x}_n\rangle$$

By applying $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{j!}(iq)^j$ to both sides of this equation
we get the Taylor-series of the exponential function.
$$e^{iq\hat{Q}(f)} |\vec{x}_1 ... \vec{x}_n\rangle
= e^{iq\sum_{k=1}^n f(\vec{x}_k)} |\vec{x}_1 ... \vec{x}_n\rangle$$

Now it is easy to prove equation (5) of the question:
$$\begin{align}
 & \hat{U}(f) |\vec{x}_1 ... \vec{x}_n\rangle \\
=&\ e^{iq\hat{Q}(f)} |\vec{x}_1 ... \vec{x}_n\rangle \\
=&\ e^{iq\sum_{k=1}^n f(\vec{x}_k)} |\vec{x}_1 ... \vec{x}_n\rangle \\
=&\ \prod_{k=1}^n e^{iqf(\vec{x}_k)} |\vec{x}_1 ... \vec{x}_n\rangle
\end{align}$$

Comment: Your conjecture is right, if I understand the notation in the question. I'm assuming that each $\vec x_n$ inside $|\cdots\rangle$ means that we've applied a factor of $\psi^\dagger(\vec x_n)$ to the vacuum state. In that case, your conjecture can be proven like this. Use the abbreviation $$Q(f)=\int f(x)\psi^\dagger(x)\psi(x).$$ Then $$[Q(f),\psi^\dagger(x)]=f(x)\psi^\dagger(x).$$ Equivalently, $$Q(f)\psi^\dagger(x)=\psi^\dagger(x)(f(x)+Q(f)).$$ This gives $$\exp(-iqQ(f))\psi^\dagger(x)\exp(iqQ(f))=\exp(iqf(x))\psi^\dagger(x).$$ To finish, use the fact that $Q(f)$ annihilates the vacuum state.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly It took me a while to digest this sketched proof and fill the gaps. Very much appreciated.